# Entity Framework maps the float datatype into double

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I am working on an asp.net mvc 3 web application using database-first approach.

I have a table called `Results` that contains two columns (`min & max`) of type `float`, but when I use the Entity Framework to map the existing database into model classes, then EF creates a class `Results` with the data type of the `min & max` fields as `double` instead of `float` as specified in the exsiting database.

So why is this behaviour happening? Will it cause any problems?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is normal behaviour, as per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896344%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Even SQL-server's `real` datatype is mapped to `double`, even though `float` would definitely be enough there.

But the type names are very confusing here. In fact [`float` (t-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173773.aspx) is the same as [`double` (.Net)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.aspx): a precision of 15 digits and a range of negative 1.79769313486232e308 to positive 1.79769313486232e308.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if your problem is identical to this or not:

http://forums.asp.net/p/1606916/4100117.aspx

But it doesn't seem like this should cause any problems.  You could lose precision with your numbers going from a double to a float, but it should still work unless you need the extra digits.

Comment: but why i will loss digits if i change a double to fload,, i tried to inser something like 1.123456789 and it was saved in the database correctly...

Comment: You could potentially lose precision because a float has a precision of 7, while a double has a precision of 15-16.  It's unlikely you'd need that type of precision unless you were doing some sort of math calculations where it was needed though.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1e65aza(v=vs.100).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/678hzkk9(v=vs.100).aspx

Those 2 links are for the float and double data types.