# LINQ Sum method error

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-core

Following `LINQ` query gives me the error shown below:

**Error**:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Double' to type 'System.Nullable'1[System.Single]'.

**LINQ query**:

```
using (gEn myEntities = new gEn)
{
    var load = (from items in myEntities.Orders
    select items.PayO).Sum();
}
```

**Model**:

```
Public class Order
{
    Public int OrdersId {get; set;}
    Public float? PayO {get; set;}
}
```

**NOTE**:

1. The PayO column of corresponding Orders table in SQL Server 2012 is of type `real` and all its values are greater than zero (if that matters)
2. For testing purposes, in the above query if I replace **select items.PayO** by, say, `select 2` the `LINQ` query works fine and returns the sum of 2 repeated as many times as the number of rows in the table. For example if table has 4 rows, the `LINQ` query will return `8` (i.e 2+2+2+2)

Comment: Cant duplicate this at all - that code will not throw that error based on what your claiming.

Comment: Take a look at [this table on msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896344(v=vs.110).aspx) where you can see that both the `float` and `real` types map to `Edm.Double`. Your model datatype should be `double?`.

Comment: Is `PayO` holding currency values? If so, `real` would be an inappropriate choice of data type.

Comment: This exception is not related to `Sum()`! It is related to your mapping `gEn` with the database.

Comment: Can you make this query: `(from items in myEntities.Orders
select items.PayO).ToList()` and see what happened? What is result.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10290432/entity-framework-maps-the-float-datatype-into-double

Comment: @spender Yes, `PayO` is holding currency. If I change `real` to `double`, will if cause any issue? It's a `Code First` app and `add-migration` command in VS2015 created the DB from the models.

Comment: You're going to run into problems storing currency in a floating point type. Take a read: [What every programmer should know about floating point arithmetic](http://floating-point-gui.de/). When storing fractional parts of a currency (cents, for instance), there are many values that simply cannot be represented precisely by floating point numbers. When it comes to accounting, this imprecision can accumulate and give you a headache. Net and SqlServer both have decimal datatypes, and EF will map these correctly. Decimal is the appropriate type for currencies. Not using it might be painful.

Comment: try this one `myEntities.Orders.Sum( o => o.PayO);`

Comment: @kat1330 Your following suggestion worked (thank you). If you post it as a Response (with a brief explanation, if any), I'll mark it as an answer: `(from items in myEntities.Orders select items.PayO).ToList().Sum()`

Comment: @StephenMuecke I am also surprised on why it does not work. But for some reason (or maybe reason**s**) the following worked: `(from items in myEntities.Orders select items.PayO).ToList().Sum()`

Comment: I suspect that is because you materializing the collection to an in memory set first, so the value is now `float?` and your summing the values from your collection, as opposed to summing the raw values in the database via the sql query (which is `double`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am suspecting (cannot proof at this moment) that you have the problem with query materialisation!

When you execute this query:

```
var load = (from items in myEntities.Orders
    select items.PayO).Sum();
```

It will be translated to this query:

```
SELECT SUM(PayO) FROM Order;
```

At this point, your query cannot handle `null` values!

But when you do this (which I mentioned in comment above):

```
var pays = (from items in myEntities.Orders select items.PayO).ToList();
```

Your query will be executed and you will have in-memory list of `float?`. At this point you can execute aggregation because `Sum()` [is able to handle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb156065(v=vs.110).aspx) `null` values.

```
var load = pays.Sum();
```

`load` is your sum.

Comment: As I mentioned in my note 1 above all the values are not nullable (i.e. > 0). But, I think what you and user `@StephenMuecke` have suspected above, your suggested solution (that worked) may have something to do with in-memory list when executing `ToList()`. Thank you for shedding some light on possible causes of the issue and its possible workable solution.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see in the code.
PayO is nullable, and the error clearly saying that it can't convert null to double.
So you need to update your query to be like

```
using (gEn myEntities = new gEn) 
{
    var load = (from items in myEntities.Orders
    where items.PayO != NULL
    select items.PayO).Sum(); 
}
```