# EF6 gets float as int

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

I'm getting Customers from context but whilst amount is saved as 12.5 in the Db I get 125.

The weird part is that by using:

```
return await Context.Payments.Where(p => p.Id == 82).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

I get 12.5

But when I use:

```
await Context.Set<Customer>()
                    .Include(c => c.Illness)
                    .Include(d => d.WeightHistory)
                    .Include(e => e.ShowUps)
                    .Include(f => f.Programs)
                    .Include(g => g.Payments)
                    .ToListAsync();
```

The payment amount is 125.

Any idea why this happens?

Amount property in Payment model:

```
 public float Amount
    {
        get
        {
            return _Amount;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_Amount == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _Amount = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

[image: Payment struct]

[image: db value]

[image]

Comment: HINT: `return await Context.Payments.Where(p => p.Id == 67).FirstOrDefaultAsync();` gives you 12.5 for record id=67. What is the id for record from Payments table with amount of 125.0?

Comment: ^-- along what @yW0K5o said you can retrieve it this way: `var payment = customers.SelectMany(_ => _.Payments).FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == 67);` assuming `customers` is the variable assigned to the result of the 2nd statement in question.

Comment: When my application starts I load all customers including their payments etc and then I use each customers payments as a Datagrid's Itemsource. I don't need customer'w with id==67 payments, this was only for debugging reasons. The thing is that when I get just a payment from the Database the amount is correctly 12.5 but when I use Linq's Include(); to get all Customers including their payments I get the value without the decimal point!

Comment: Can you show use your `DataGrid` the XAML and codebehind? How you are setting the ItemsSource how you are defining the columns

Comment: @RandRandom the XAML part is correct. As you can see at the pictures I added the value is 125 since repository.

Comment: You know that your screenshot shows the Id `82` and not `67` as your "simple" example states?

Comment: Also notice that the date isn't correct either your screenshot of debug session shows a time "12:00:00" instead of "00:00:00"

Comment: @RandRandom it is an example. the problem exists in all decimal records. In two last screenshots you can clearly see that while the value of amount for the record with Id 82 is 12.5 in Db, ef6 gets 125 when i use include.

Comment: Are you using EDMX (database first)? If yes, try to update the EDMX model.

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't have an exact answer for your problem, I would say that the real problem is that you are using a `float` for an "Amount", especially what seems like a money amount. `Floats` are known to have issues with precision in `SQL`, I recommend that you switch the type to be a `decimal(19,2)` and you should see your problem disappear.

Comment: Although I agree that `float` is an incorrect type usage for storing currency/money related data I am willing to bet the problem the OP is experiencing is related to something else like comparing different records. At this point though it is just a guess because there is no [mcve] and not enough information in the question to be sure (of anything).

Comment: @Igor I added some more info, what else would you need to help you understand my situation?

Comment: [link](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=92484) Here you can find exactly the same problem as me

Comment: Take a look at this and see if it helps: mhttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/10290432/entity-framework-maps-the-float-datatype-into-double

Comment: @axilleas-kar What happens when you change the `SQL` datatype fro `Amount` from `float` to `decimal(19,2)` and in your `POCO` `Amount` to `decimal`?

Comment: @SerjSagan I did this and now values are stored like 12.50 in db and i get 1250... Its very strange because when I change the order of includes and set Iclude(payments) first, the payments are got right... it might be an ef6 bug..

Comment: @axilleas-kar Does anything change when you decorate the `Amount` property on your `Payment` class with: `[Column(TypeName = "decimal(19,2)")]`? Certainly sounds like a weird `EF6` bug. Make sure that both `Amount` and `_Amount` are of type `decimal`.

Comment: Nothing worked. Also tried modelBuilder.Entity<Payment>().Property(x => x.Amount).HasPrecision(18, 3); but still same. I now preload all payments so they are properly stored in ef6 cache and it works because there are not too many payments, but this shouldn't be the solution...

Comment: In the comment above you said that if you `Include` your `Payments` first then it loads correctly... so why don't you just do that instead of caching them all?